# App to display IP address in menu bar?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, menu-bar, network

I deal with a lot of external servers where the firewall must be configured to allow SSH access.  I frequently need to know my external IP address, and it changes often.

- external IPv4 address desired
- bonus if I can choose IPv6 if needed
- bonus if I can copy the value to the clipboard to paste elsewhere

Are there applications that will determine a Mac's external IP address and display it in the menu bar?

Comment: Hi, you can use Find My IP https://www.producthunt.com/posts/find-my-ip

Comment: BitBar will do it and much more!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This small application runs in the background and shows the current IP
>   dddress of your Mac in the menu bar. There are options available to
>   customize the appearance of the menu entry. The IP dddress is updated
>   regulary. Switch on the Router option if you are behind a router or
>   gateway. You can still see your local IP address in the menu.

https://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Software/IPinmenubar.shtml

> Do you need your computers IP address often? If so, IPMenulet is
>   likely the quickest way to have the number handy all the time, it’s a
>   free and simple menu item that displays your current external IP
>   address in the Mac OS X menu bar, there’s no other frills or features.
>
> You can download IPMenulet now (direct .dmg download – link changed
>   visit dev site instead) or visit the developers website here for more
>   information and to view the simple tools source code.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/30/show-ip-address-menu-bar-mac/

**And the associated Google Search :**

https://www.google.fr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ip+menubar+os+x&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=N-0WVve4KMe7bpKHpogO

Comment: I apparently suck at google.

Comment: Once you've copied IP In Menu Bar from the mounted DMG to your Applications folder, you can make a Duplicate copy of it, run each copy, and set one to display your Router IP so you have both internal and external IPs in your Menu Bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to clog up your status bar, here is an alternate solution. Save the following AppleScript code as an application in Script Editor.app.

Any time you run your new app (double clicking it in Finder), it will display a dialog with your current external IP address and copy it to the clipboard.

```
set theIP to do shell script "curl ifconfig.co"

set the clipboard to theIP

activate
display dialog "Your current IP Address is: " & theIP & linefeed ¬
    & linefeed & "     It has been copied to the Clipboard." with icon 2 buttons "OK" default button 1 ¬
    with title "Current External IP Address" giving up after 10
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to introduce you to the Xbar app. This is an open-source project; please check the plugins you would like, including IP-related ones. [xbar site] [1](https://xbarapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Skeebus is free, available through the Mac Store, and has recently been updated:
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/skeebus/id1035480615

Looks much better than the previous suggestions (which I am sure where fine at the time).

Comment: er... was free. as of 2018-03-01, now $0.99